# I want to better understand XSLT 1.0 nested grouping using Muenchian grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML data and would like to group it by INSPTR and ELVINSP_DT. Questions at the end of the post.

Here is my XML:

```
<AS400_ELVPINS00Collection>
  <ObjList>
    <AS400_ELVPINS00>
      <ID>123456</ID>
      <ELVINSP_DT>2014-05-01</ELVINSP_DT>
      <DetailData>Out Sick</DetailData>
      <INSPTR>
        <ID>555123</ID>
        <INSPTR_NAME>Doe, John P</INSPTR_NAME>
        <MoreDetailData>Northeast Region</MoreDetailData>
      </INSPTR>
    </AS400_ELVPINS00>
    <AS400_ELVPINS00>
      <ID>123459</ID>
      <ELVINSP_DT>2014-05-02</ELVINSP_DT>
      <DetailData>Nobody showed up</DetailData>
      <INSPTR>
        <ID>555123</ID>
        <INSPTR_NAME>Doe, John P</INSPTR_NAME>
        <MoreDetailData>Northeast Region</MoreDetailData>
      </INSPTR>
    </AS400_ELVPINS00>
    <AS400_ELVPINS00>
      <ID>123463</ID>
      <ELVINSP_DT>2014-05-01</ELVINSP_DT>
      <DetailData>Job Location was clear</DetailData>
      <INSPTR>
        <ID>555124</ID>
        <INSPTR_NAME>Smith, John T</INSPTR_NAME>
        <MoreDetailData>South Central Region</MoreDetailData>
      </INSPTR>
    </AS400_ELVPINS00>
  </ObjList>
</AS400_ELVPINS00Collection>
```

I'd like the data listed like this:

```
Doe, John P  
 2014-05-01 - Out Sick  
 2014-05-02 - Nobody showed up  
Smith, John T  
 2014-05-01 - Job Location was clear
```

Here is what I'm trying for XSLT:

```
  <xsl:key name="keyInsptr" match="ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00" use="INSPTR" />
  <xsl:key name="keyDate" match="ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00" use="ELVINSP_DT" />

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <xsl:for-each select="ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="INSPTR/INSPTR_NAME"/>

        <!-- This part works --> 
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="INSPTR/INSPTR_NAME" />
        </fo:block>

        <!-- This part DOES NOT work -->
        <xsl:variable name="vrInsptID">
          <xsl:value-of select="INSPTR/INSPTR_NAME"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="lstInsp" select="ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00[INSPTR/INSPTR_NAME=vrInsptrID]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="lstInsp[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('keyDate',ELVINSP_DT)[1])]">
          <fo:block>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="dateFormat">
              <xsl:with-param name="value" select="lstInsp/ELVINSP_DT" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>


      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:flow>
```

I understand that generate-id creates a unique 'id' at runtime for an element, so I am assuming that generate-id(.) will generate an id for each ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00 element to use in the match, correct?

What is generate-id(key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)[1]) doing? What kind of results does that make? I'm trying to visualize this.

When I do the 'for-each' on keyInsptr, what Node-set am I working with inside that for-each?

How do I get the inner 'for-each' to cycle through the dates correctly?

I am not just looking to get this working, but to also understand how it should work. Thank you.

Comment: The web is full of explanations of Muenchian grouping, I suggest you study [the one by Jeni Tennison](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: Thank you, I had already read that one yesterday. Just didn't fully understand it. Looking at your answer below. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, the answer below is written by Martin Honnen, not me. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Muenchian grouping and don't understand the concept then I don't think it is a good idea starting a project with nested grouping and two keys. As for your problems to understand the predicate `generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)[1])`, it is just making sure the for-each processes the first item in each group based on the key value as the expression `key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)` finds all items of the same key value, the positional predicate `key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)[1]` takes the first of those items and the generate-id check is just the XSLT/XPath 1.0 way of comparing the identity of two nodes (with XPath 2.0 you could just write `[. is key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)[1]]` although you would use `for-each-group` instead). Thus the

```
  <xsl:for-each select="ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('keyInsptr', INSPTR)[1])]">
```

processes the first `AS400_ELVPINS00` (in document order) of each group having the same key value.

Now to extend the grouping you usually concatenate key values with a separator character not in the expected key values so with

```
  <xsl:key name="keyDate" match="ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00" use="concat(INSPTR, '|', ELVINSP_DT)" />
```

and

```
    <xsl:for-each select="key('keyInsptr', INSPTR)[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('keyDate', concat(INSPTR, '|', ELVINSP_DT))[1])]">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="dateFormat">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="ELVINSP_DT" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

you would implement a second level of grouping.

Comment: Okay, so with my example data, key('keyInsptr',INSPTR) will give me/return/contain two groups of ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00 objects, correct?

Comment: I understanding having a key-pair for the second grouping, that makes sense. However, I am now getting this message: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.  ...PTR)[generate-id(.)=generate-id( -->concat(INSPTR, '|', ELVINSP_DT)<-- [1])]      Does it matter that ELVINSP_DT is not a child of INSPTR, but at the same level?

Comment: The key function call is inside a predicate so it is done relative to the selected `AS400_ELVPINS00` elements. The select `select="ObjList/AS400_ELVPINS00"` selects all `AS400_ELVPINS00` elements, the predicate then filters them based on the condition; in the condition the key call `key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)` computes a node-set of all items with the same key value (with the same `INSPTR` value), the positional predicate `[1]` takes the first of them and the generate-id check makes sure the for-each processes only one item for each group, namely the first in each group.

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to use the key correctly: <xsl:for-each select="key('keyInsptr',INSPTR)[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('keyDate',concat(INSPTR, '|', ELVINSP_DT))[1])]">

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, the nested predicate lacked the key function call, I had just written the key value compuation. Now corrected.

Comment: Awesome, sometimes it helps to have a person explain it so I can wrap my head around it. Thanks!